# Me sale un error 1046 al crear una base de datos

Tags: sql, mariadb

Error
SQL query: Copy

```
--
-- Base de datos: `ServiciosPublicos`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `cliente`
--

CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `contrasenia` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

y el código que yo usé fue:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.2.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 02-04-2023 a las 02:03:34
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.27-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 8.2.0

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `ServiciosPublicos`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `cliente`
--

CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `contrasenia` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: El codigo no puede ser mas claro... "#1046 - No database selected", te falta decirle que base de datos usaras

Comment: 1. XAMPP nada tiene que ver con la pregunta, ya que es una herramienta nada más. ¿Con qué base de datos (MySQL, MariaDB...) estás trabajando? 2. Tal como te indicaron, el error es bastante claro: "No database selected". 3. No pongas un _clickbait_ en el título de la pregunta: en su lugar, debes describir el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].

Comment: Añade al comienzo del script [`USE db_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html) indicando el nombre de la BD donde quieres correr todueso